# What does Cramer's model say?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I know that Cramer's model is stated as follows:

"With a probability =1, the relation

$$\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{(\log p_n)^2}=1$$
is satisfied"

Could someone explain to me in "softer" words what this means?  I have a clear notation $\limsup$ and $\liminf$

For example, if I write this
$\liminf_{n\to\infty} (p_{n+1}-p_n)=2$, I know you mean that there are infinitely many primes such that if difference is 2.

In the case of the cramer model, what does it say?  I think I'm confused by the fact of the quotient or the text "With a probability =1"

I would appreciate an explanation, it is the first time that I approach this result and I would like it to be clear to me.

Comment: It might mean that the set of all subsequences of natural numbers that do not satisfy this relationship has a measure of zero.

Comment: @TravorLZH It means that Cramer replaces the prime (gaps) by some random variables that satisfy the statement. Most of the random model follows from the (wrong but "asymptotically correct") asumption that the random variables $X_{p,N}=n\bmod p$ are independent in $p\le \sqrt{N}$ when $n$ is drawn uniformly in $[1,N]$.

Comment: The Cramer model can be used to support conjectures like the twin prime conjecture by a heuristic , but the problem with this formulation is that it is conjectured that there is no prime gap with magnitude $\log^2(p_n)$ or more for which we also have heuristical evidence. Sure that the model actually predicts this limit ?

Comment: As far as I understood the Cramer model assumes that a random number near a large number $x$ is prime with probability $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$. How does this imply the given limit ?

Comment: PNT actually suggests that $\sum_{n\le x}{p_{n+1}-p_n\over\log n}\sim x$, so I wonder if this average order statement answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ignoring the "probability 1" comment, the equation:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{(\log p_n)^2} = 1$$

can (non-rigorously) be rewritten as $\limsup_{n\to\infty} p_{n+1}-p_n = (\log p_n)^2$. Strictly speaking, this makes no sense --- $n$ is not a free variable on the left-hand side (we are taking a limit over it), but on the right-hand side it is.
Still, it can be useful to translate your intuition (which I will rewrite as)

> for arbitrarily large $n$, *there exists* prime gaps of size *at least* 2.

to

> for arbitrarily large $n$, *all* prime gaps (asymptotically) are of size of *at most* $(\log p_n)^2$.

So instead of claiming that there are some prime gaps that are incredibly small (an "existence" result that is a "lower bound"), it is stating that (in an asymptotic sense) prime gaps cannot get "too large" (or a "universal result" that is an "upper bound").
Note that the heuristic form $\limsup_{n\infty} (p_{n+1}-p_n) = (\log p_n)^2$ is *stronger* than having written $O((\log p_n)^2)$ on the RHS --- it is claiming to pin down a precise constant.

Now, what does the probability 1 comment mean?
The primes $\mathcal{P} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ are a fixed (deterministic) subset.
Cramer's random model replaces $\mathcal{P}$ with a certain *random subset* of $\mathbb{N}$.
Formally (this is from [*Cramer vs. Cramer. On Cramer's Probabilistic
Model For Primes* by Pintz](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/functiones-et-approximatio-commentarii-mathematici/volume-37/issue-2/Cram%c3%a9r-vs-Cram%c3%a9r-On-Cram%c3%a9rs-probabilistic-model-for-primes/10.7169/facm/1229619660.full)) this can be defined as follows.

> For $n\geq 3$, define the *independent* set of random variables $\xi(n)$, supported on $\{0,1\}$ where
>
> $$\Pr[\xi(n) = 1]= \frac{1}{\log n},\qquad \Pr[\xi(n) = 0] = 1 - \frac{1}{\log n}$$

The collection of $(\xi(n))_{n\geq 3}$ can be seen as defining a random subset of $\mathbb{N}_{\geq 3}$, e.g. a "random model of the primes" (we view this as being a random model of the primes as each $\xi(n)$ has the "right density" according to the prime number theorem).
The statement

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{(\log p_n)^2} = 1$$

then holds with probability $1$ over the choice of random model of the primes $(\xi(n))_{n\geq 3}$, and more properly can be written as

$$\Pr_{(\xi(n))_{n\geq 3}}\left[\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\xi(n+1)-\xi(n)}{(\log \xi(n))^2}=1\right]=1$$